# Angular js and restful into android app

Tags: android, angularjs, rest

I have developed a app using angular js and restful webservices can i bundle this app in apk and how. its now only browser bases.please give provide any link of the bundling.

Answer (score 0):

Use a webview to load the application. ( This is hybrid way )

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: As far as I know, webviews don't produce apks

Comment: Yes you can use Apache Cordova. It basically does the same thing

Comment: @TimCastelijns You are right but you can always create a simple wrapper which simply loads the webview

Comment: Honestly, that's a really bad solution

Comment: Thats how hybrid applications work. Check out Apache Cordova they create a wrapper around a webview and its a pretty valid way.

Comment: It depends on your need - if you require multiple platform support then use Cordova but if only Android then use webview. Also don't forget to mark the question as answered if it solves your issue.

Comment: I am using cordova can you give me a link for it because in Internet its damn confusing n i am new to this so dont know what 2 follow

Answer (score 0):

you can check with ionic framework .This framework build with angular js and apache cordova.Kindly view this doc http://ionicframework.com/ for move info